# pandas groupby and sum if condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

that's my data:

```
ID;combined_date;EAN;quantity;price1;price2;price3
22138999;20200901;1111111111111;1;5.00;10.00;15.00
22137507;20200901;2222222222222;1;5.00;10.00;15.00
22139440;20200901;1111111111111;1;5.00;15.00;20.00
22138875;20200901;1111111111111;1;5.00;10.00;15.00
```

I want to group if the EAN is same as another EAN strong textin this data & price1 + price2 + price 3 is also same as the first EAN. Furthermore, the quantity column must summed. price1,2,3 should not be summed. ID = index

Desired output:

```
ID;combined_date;EAN;quantity;price1;price2;price3
22138999;20200901;1111111111111;2;5.00;10.00;15.00
22137507;20200901;2222222222222;1;5.00;10.00;15.00
22139440;20200901;1111111111111;1;5.00;15.00;20.00
```

So far, I'm able to read the data from an excel file and get filtered output based on some filter conditions but I don't get any further with grouping this data.

```
import pandas as pd

current_file = slsrpt_new.xls

data = pd.read_excel(current_file)
data.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

filter_brand = ['some filter']
filter_sales_channel = ['some filter']

data = data.astype({'EAN': 'str'}).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
data['price1'] = data['price1'].astype('float').map("{:,.2f}".format)
data['price2'] = data['price2'].astype('float').map("{:,.2f}".format)
data['price3'] = data['price3'].astype('float').map("{:,.2f}".format)

data["combined_date"] = data["Year"].astype(str) + data['Month'].astype('int64').map("{:02}".format) + data['Day'].astype('int64').map("{:02}".format)

to_slsrpt = data[data['brand'].isin( filter_brand ) & (data["sales_channel"].isin( filter_sales_channel))]

print(to_slsrpt[['combined_date', 'EAN', 'quantity', 'price1', 'price2', 'price3']])
```

Thanks.

Comment: post you witten code

Comment: sorry, done....

Answer (score 0):

you can group data by more than one condition:

```
df.groupby(['EAN','price1','price2','price3']).sum()
```

gives you

```
                                    quantity
EAN           price1 price2 price3          
1111111111111 5.00   10.00  15.00          2
                     15.00  20.00          1
2222222222222 5.00   10.00  15.00          1
```